# Obtain the index of the maximum element

Tags: c#, linq

Given such a list:

```
        List<int> intList = new List<int>();
        intList.Add(5);
        intList.Add(10);
        intList.Add(15);
        intList.Add(46);
```

how do you obtain the index of the maximum element in the list? In this case, it's at index 3.

Edit: It's a shame that standard LINQ doesn't ship this functionalities.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is a simple* and relatively efficient** solution:

```
int indexMax
    = !intList.Any() ? -1 :
    intList
    .Select( (value, index) => new { Value = value, Index = index } )
    .Aggregate( (a, b) => (a.Value > b.Value) ? a : b )
    .Index;
```

1. The `!intList.Any() ? -1 :` will force a `-1` if the list is empty;
2. The `Select` will project each `int` element into an anonymous type with two properties: `Value` and `Index`;
3. The `Aggregate` will get the element with the highest `Value`;
4. Finally, we get the `Index` of the chosen element.

* Simplicity is relative. The aim here was to reach a balance of readability and still only scan the list once.

** The allocation of lots of new objects during the `Select` is probably wasteful. As some people tested, it doesn't perform well for large lists.

**EDIT 1:** empty list check added.

**EDIT 2:** added caveats about performance.

Comment: Not simple, not fast.

Comment: Maybe it's not as simple as you would like, but it's  the fastest presented here. Extract it to a extension method and forget about it. I'd love to see your alternative. Downvoting the best answer because you didn't like it is just childish.

Comment: If it is faster than Matt Howells and Jon Skeets I will repent myself and never use for again.

Comment: I'd love to see some benchmarks. I doubt that you'll find any meaningful performance difference between my answer and Skeets'. To be honest, if I'd use any here today, I'd go with Adinochestva's for its simplicity.

Comment: This method was about three times slower than Skeets' in my test (List of 100000 doubles), which was again around 30% slower than a custom-made method.

Answer (score 51):

this way :

```
var maxIndex = foo.IndexOf(foo.Max());
```

Comment: This is clean and short, but requires up to two full passes through the list to obtain the index. If you need it faster, you should use a for loop and keep track of the index as you go.

Comment: It's still O(n), and the second pass might not be a full pass. I'd go with this code if performance if not a big issue.

Comment: oneliners never lose their charm. +1

Comment: I know it's still O(N). But it's unnecessarily inefficient by going over the array twice.

Answer (score 15):

Here's a custom LINQ method which I believe does what you want. (I previously had another which does a projection, but you can just call Select to do that, as you only need the index.)

```
public static int MaxIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    IComparer<T> comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Empty sequence");
        }
        int maxIndex = 0;
        T maxElement = iterator.Current;
        int index = 0;
        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            index++;
            T element = iterator.Current;
            if (comparer.Compare(element, maxElement) > 0)
            {
                maxElement = element;
                maxIndex = index;
            }
        }
        return maxIndex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like the right idea (cursory look, it's late). I'd use `selector` as the name of your second parameter to match the Enumerable.Max() methods.

Comment: @280Z28: I think you must have been looking at the old version - I got rid of the selector bit...

Answer (score 5):

Here's how to do it in one (long) line using LINQ, with just a single pass through the collection. It should work for any `IEnumerable<int>`, not just lists.

```
int maxIndex = intList
    .Select((x, i) => new { Value = x, Index = i })
    .Aggregate
        (
            new { Value = int.MinValue, Index = -1 },
            (a, x) => (a.Index < 0) || (x.Value > a.Value) ? x : a,
            a => a.Index
        );
```

Here's the non-LINQ equivalent of the above, using a `foreach` loop. (Again, just a single pass through the collection, and should work for any `IEnumerable<int>`.)

```
int maxIndex = -1, maxValue = int.MinValue, i = 0;
foreach (int v in intList)
{
    if ((maxIndex < 0) || (v > maxValue))
    {
        maxValue = v;
        maxIndex = i;
    }
    i++;
}
```

If you know that the collection is an `IList<int>` then a plain `for` loop is probably the easiest solution:

```
int maxIndex = -1, maxValue = int.MinValue;
for (int i = 0; i < intList.Count; i++)
{
    if ((maxIndex < 0) || (intList[i] > maxValue))
    {
        maxValue = intList[i];
        maxIndex = i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't improve on Jon Skeet's answer for the general case, so I am going for the 'high performance' prize in the specific case of a list of ints.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int IndexOfMaximumElement(this IList<int> list)
    {
        int size = list.Count;

        if (size < 2)
            return size - 1;

        int maxValue = list[0];
        int maxIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i)
        {
            int thisValue = list[i];
            if (thisValue > maxValue)
            {
                maxValue = thisValue;
                maxIndex = i;
            }
        }

        return maxIndex;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution:

```
public static int IndexOfMax(this IList<int> source)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (source.Count == 0)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("List contains no elements");

    int maxValue = source[0];
    int maxIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < source.Count; i++)
    {
        int value = source[i];
        if (value > maxValue)
        {
            maxValue = value;
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return maxIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the non-linq method if you like:

```
private int ReturnMaxIdx(List<int> intList)
        {
            int MaxIDX = -1;
            int Max = -1;

            for (int i = 0; i < intList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    Max = intList[0];
                    MaxIDX = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (intList[i] > Max)
                    {
                        Max = intList[i];
                        MaxIDX = i;
                    }
                }
            }

            return MaxIDX;
        }
```

This is a single pass through the list at least.

Hope this helps,

Kyle

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom function, using Max() and IndexOf() cost more.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified.

```
int MaxIndex = list.DefaultIfEmpty().Select((v, i) => new { v, i }).Aggregate((a, b) => (a.v > b.v) ? a : b).i;
```