# Get index of List.Max?

Tags: c#, list, max

I have the list

```
List<double> nums = new List<double> {0.2, 5.0, 12.0};
```

and I am trying to find the element for which the `element-element^2` is greatest. I can run

```
nums.Max(num => num - Math.Pow(num, 2))
```

to find the maximum but how can I then get the index of this element that identifies as yielding the greatest value when evaluating `num - Math.Pow(num, 2)`? `IndexOf` won't work because the value returned by `Max` is not the value of the actual element that yields the greatest value when applied but the value of the whole expression.

I have looked at [Obtain the Index of the Maximum Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136174/obtain-the-index-of-the-maximum-element) but that seems to cover `Max` in the case where it returns the actual element and thus `IndexOf` works. I can only image that there is a simple approach to solve my case because `Max` iterates the list anyways.

Comment: If by chance you're dealing with only positive numbers, you are guaranteed that the max `element - element^2` comes from the max element. So, you could return that exact element and use IndexOf without needing to perform the equation.

Comment: I think, you can replace `Value = value,` to `Value = value - Math.Pow(value, 2)` in the referenced sample. The result will valid for you.

Comment: Note that `num - Math.Pow(num, 2)` is only an example. There are other examples where the calculation is dependent on other variables and cannot be rewritten.

Comment: [How do I get the index of the highest value in an array using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462699/how-do-i-get-the-index-of-the-highest-value-in-an-array-using-linq)

Comment: @wakeel - you meant to say the max result comes from the min element if only positive numbers, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the index of the highest value in an array using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462699/how-do-i-get-the-index-of-the-highest-value-in-an-array-using-linq)

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes it's just easier to do it with a good old loop

```
double maxValue = Double.MinValue;
int indexOfMax = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < nums.Count; i++) {
    double x = nums[i];
    double y = x - x * x;
    if (y > maxValue) {
        maxValue = y;
        indexOfMax = i;
    }
}
double element = nums[indexOfMax];
```

Comment: But that is so verbose compared to the fact that the `Max` code covers so much of the problem :/

Comment: I mean, `Max` does already iterate the whole list and finds the max value of the applied expression - then you only need to get the index of the element for which the value is greatest...

Comment: Its not much more to write than with a working LINQ solution, easier to understand and probably faster. But it's a matter of taste. Your `Max` solution is shorter but does not work.

Answer (score 3):

In one Linq query (not guaranteed to have the best performance though)

```
List<double> nums = new List<double> { 0.2, 5.0, 12.0 };
var index = nums.Select((n, i) => new { Result = n - n * n, Index = i })
                .Aggregate(new { Result = Double.MinValue, Index = -1 }, (a, b) => (a.Result > b.Result) ? a : b)
                .Index;
```

A more efficient approach doing it just in one parsing of the list is to create your own `.Max()` extension and then call it on the list.

```
public static int MaxIndexByCustomRule(this IEnumerable<double> sequence)
    {
        int index = 0;
        int maxIndex = -1;
        double maxResult = double.MinValue;
        foreach (var value in sequence)
        {
            var tempResult = value - value * value;

            if (tempResult > maxResult)
            {
                maxResult = tempResult;
                maxIndex = index;
            }

            index++;
        }
        return maxIndex;
    }
```

Call:

```
List<double> nums = new List<double> { 0.2, 5.0, 12.0 };
nums.MaxIndexByCustomRule();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq. Select the element and its index and calculate value for each element. Then sort (by descending, in your case) and take top element. Same text as code:

```
List<double> nums = new List<double> { 0.2, 5.0, 12.0 };

var index = nums.Select((d, i) => new {index = i, value = d - d * d})
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.value)
    .Take(1)
    .Select(x => (int?) x.index)
    .FirstOrDefault();

if (index == null)
    Console.WriteLine("nums is empty");
else
    Console.WriteLine($"index is {index}");
```

Comment: Nice solution @Aleks

Comment: This is inherently inefficient. Sorts a whole list just to pick one element.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias as far as I know .NET after version >= 4 use a [quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) instead of full sort if there is `Take` after `OrderBy`

Comment: @Aleks Andreev I checked the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs.html#e449fbc07f49dc52) and also made some performance tests, and I can't confirm this optimization (.NET Framework 4.7.2). Do you have any reference?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias My fault. This optimization was introduced in .NetCore and not available for regular .NET framework. Source code is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/c3c0efd9029370ab9762ee254e3db8b8e3dddf34/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/OrderedEnumerable.cs#L370)

Answer (score -3):

```
    private static int index = -1;
    private static double value = Double.MinValue;
    [TestMethod]
    public void MaxTest()
    {

        List<double> nums = new List<double> { 0.2, 5.0, 12.0 };
        var x = nums.Max(num => Transform(num));
    }


    public double Transform(double n)
    {
        var r = n - Math.Pow(n, 2);
        if (r > value)
        {
            value = r;
            index++;
        }

        return r;
    }
```

If you are intending to capture the index of the max element I would recommend to use the first solution in this post by using the traditional loop. Here is something you can do if you still want to use the max function using a delegate.